# Python gzip.open() behaves differently on Linux/Mac

Tags: python, json, binary, gzip

I have the follow code.

```
j = gzip.open(os.path.join(datapath, file), mode='r').read()
j = json.loads(j)
```

On Mac, it successfully loads the .json.gz file. On Linux, it protests:

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

I am not sure how it is finding bytes when mode='r'. I wonder if anybody has any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried skipping the `read()` and using `json.load()` instead of `json.loads()`?

Comment: Are you using the same version of Python on the two systems?

Comment: For that use case, you should not be opening your file in text mode (`r`) and rather use binary (`rb`) instead... The reads will then return `bytes` and not `str`.